# How to detect unicode character while file write operation

Tags: php, icalendar, fwrite, string-function

I copied and pasted the content into my text area and stored it in the database then I found Unicode characters as shown in the attached image in my database. How can I detect or replace them while creating a .ics file from this data?

[image]

When I fetch from the database and try to write a description in a file or log this data it prints something like the below.

```
 jedes Wetter.\r\\n\r\\nDa\r\n mit dein Rasen such
```

instead, It should be like

```
 jedes Wetter.\r\n\r\nDa\r\n mit dein Rasen such
```

It prints double \ before `n`

I am creating a .ics file from this. It breaks after `jedes Wetter.`

Comment: I doubt this is actually binary (but I can't be 100% sure). Probably what you really need to do is make sure your website fully supports UTF-8.

Comment: That looks like it says `00 0D`  - which would mean, it is just a simple carriage return then.

Comment: There is no reason for that. If you remove or replace characters such as a newline, you distort the information.